# Google search showing AWS elastic IP instead of domain URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, google, seo

I have a web platform on AWS elastic beanstalk with domain name. However, google search shows IP address instead of domain name. It also directs to HTTP instead of HTTPS, even though I have made so HTTP redirects to HTTPS. In addition, site description is completely random.

I have meta tags with title, description, og:url and so on. My domain name is fairly new (I bought it 4 days ago), so maybe I just have to wait for Google to approve it? Or I should do any additional steps?

[image: image of how it looks like on Google search]

Comment: Whatever you are using in your "web platform", try configuring it so requests to the IP address get 301 permanent redirect to the URL.

Comment: Please edit your question to link to your website.